# Batch Get User Input To Put Into A File

Tags: batch-file

I have this code:

```
loop
echo -- File Created With LuaIDE. Do NOT Remove This Line > LuaCode.lua
set /p Lua=Lua: 
%Lua% >> LuaCode.lua
if %Lua% == "LuaIDE.Exit()" ( echo Thanks for using LuaIDE!
timeout /t 3 /nobreak >nul
exit )
goto loop
```

and what i want it to do is get User-Input and put it into a file and if the user input is `"LuaIDE.Exit()"` I would like it to say a message for 3 seconds and exit but it just says:

```
'whatever you type in' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Why does it do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@echo off
:loop
echo -- File Created With LuaIDE. Do NOT Remove This Line > LuaCode.lua
set /p Lua=Lua: 
echo %Lua%>>LuaCode.lua
if /i "%Lua%" == "LuaIDE.Exit()" echo Thanks for using LuaIDE & timeout /t 3 /nobreak >nul & exit
goto loop
```

Let me know how it works.

Comment: @stephenb It doesn't work. It doesn't give me the error but when I check the file, it just says: -- File Created With LuaIDE. Do NOT Remove This Line. Plus, when I type "LuaIDE.Exit()" It doesn't launch the exit command.

Comment: Nope, still the same output.

Comment: move the label `:loop` down one line.

Comment: Just escaped the bracts try that.

Comment: `if /i "%Lua%" == "LuaIDE.Exit()"` <--- try that

Answer (score 0):

You have a few bugs. Try this:

```
echo -- File Created With LuaIDE. Do NOT Remove This Line > LuaCode.lua

:loop
set /p Lua=Lua: 
echo %Lua% >> LuaCode.lua
if %Lua%==LuaIDE.Exit() goto exit
goto loop

:exit
echo Thanks for using LuaIDE!
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 3 -w 1 >nul
exit
```

Comment: i added quotation marks around `%Lua%` and `LuaIDE.Exit()` and it wrote: `-- File Created With LuaIDE. Do NOT Remove This Line` (Next Line) `LuaIDE.Exit()`. I typed test into the console and it didn't write it into the file.

Answer (score -1):

stop complicating a simple task....

the code is as simple as

```
@echo off
: start
echo.
set /p input= type your text here:
echo %input%>>myfile.extension
timeout /t 5 >null
cls
goto start
```

replace myfile with name of your file you want to send text.
replace extension with any that you want txt,log , etc
also you can specify path of your file e,g
echo %input%>>path/directory